# What does "at south of $100 million" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

From [this article](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2012/06/oracle-v-google-aftermath-apis-remain-free-cost-of-business-soars/2/):

> Judge Alsup did take the unusual step of appointing his own damages expert. That independent expert valued the patent case **at south of** $5 million, and valued the copyright case **at south of** $100 million.

It sounds like it means either:

> the minimum value is $100 million

or:

> the maximum value is $100 million

Comment: I think it means "below $100 million." "South" can be slang for "below" or "under."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"South" here means *less than*, a meaning derived from the fact that south is *down* on most maps, and that smaller numbers are often conceptualized as physically "lower" than larger ones.

Therefore, to select one of your alternatives, the **maximum** value is $100 million.

(Although this usage of *south* feels colloquial, it isn't particularly common - I wouldn't advise using it either in everyday speech or in formal writing. The author is presumably using it here because he's aiming for a casual, light-feeling journalistic style.)

Comment: Maps used to have east at their tops: hence *orientate*.

Comment: I believe the use of the phrase "North of <amount>" to mean "more than" is more common than using "South of" to mean less than.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz -- I'm with you.  I hear "north of" used all the time; I'm not sure I have ever heard "south of" before.

Answer (score 2):

It means "a little bit less than".  So "south of $100 million" might turn out to be, say, $96 million or $98 million.

Answer (score 0):

Since south is always below your map point, that's why people likes to use this phrase as a lower or below direction, so using north is the opposite way.

If you use south of a number you mean, the number you're referring to is lower/smaller than/ below of the number you mentioned. North is the bigger or above side.

Ex: North of 100 is just above the 100, you don't give any specific range but usually accepted as small amount bigger than 100, lets say 101,102

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. This answer repeats another answer given two years ago, and accepted (that is "south" is *less* or *lower than*). There is no point in giving the same answer as one already posted, I'm afraid.