# Meaning of "going north" idiom, in the context of poker

Tags: american-english, terminology

I'm wondering what is the meaning of "going north" ?

> Also really proud of shorting Vinny, he got caught 4 times going north... obnoxious, rude and wasn't thrown out and it was 25 dollars... full rack!

It is in a discussion on a poker player who used to scam other players

Comment: Really not convinced by these two possibilities for my case

Comment: Can you provide a few sentences from the previous paragraph so we can have more context?

Comment: It is in a discussion on a poker player who used to scam other players

Comment: It's a screenshot of a text message and I do not have more sentences before this one

Comment: It should be noted that "going south" is a common idiom, implying that the situation is getting worse somehow.

Comment: Relevant: [What does south of a million dollars mean](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72545/what-does-at-south-of-100-million-mean)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Poker,

***Go north*** often means   sneaking/adding chips to the stack in front of you on the table*. It is possible that the subject got caught rearranging/hiding the chips in front of them.

***Go South*** means removing chips from the table  to reduce the stake. This is considered bad manners, and is often called 'ratholing'

It is not just Poker...the expression is often used by financial/real-estate/etc  agents.

**North of a price** means *over* the price.

> used to say that an amount is more than the stated amount:

[Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/north-of-sth)

*South of a price* is less...

---

Also...

***short someone***

usually means give less that what was due, possibly indicating not paying off *vales*, or not meeting an 'all in' due to short stack count.

***full rack***

...refers to a rack of chips by denomination. That would be 5 stacks of 20 each.  A *stack* would refer to the chips stacked in front of the player, usually 20-35.

[For more information,](https://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/27/casino-amp-cardroom-poker/going-quot-north-quot-via-chips-hand-ruling-1429294/)

---

(*I have also heard at least 2 references to the phrase used to mean going to the bathroom, but I am still trying to confirm that.)

Comment: ...and no, I am not a degenerate gambler.

Comment: I have corrected some inaccuracies in the answer.

Comment: "adding chips to his stack during a tournament or during a cash game hand" should be the correct traduction, thanks